# Turning off automatic hyperlinks

Tags: front-end, undocumented, hyperlink

Recently (I only noticed in V12.2), website URLs, such as https://www.wolfram.com, became active in text cells in notebooks.  The "hot" nature makes the links hard to edit, since any click on them calls up a browser.  Is there a way to turn it off and back on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functionality is controlled by setting the cell option on the desired cell(s):

```
CodeAssistOptions -> {"AutoDetectHyperlinks" -> False}  (* Off *)
CodeAssistOptions -> {"AutoDetectHyperlinks" -> True}   (* On  *)
```

The option can also be applied globally by setting it for the Front End:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 CodeAssistOptions -> {"AutoDetectHyperlinks" -> False}]
```

The option can be applied to a single notebook, which (as usual) will override the Front End setting:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 CodeAssistOptions -> {"AutoDetectHyperlinks" -> True}]
```